# How can I remove badly named collection from mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have accidentally created a couple of collections with names similar to below, and so far, I have not been able to drop them.  I'm guessing the MongoDB shell doesn't like the `/` or the `:` or the extraneous `.`, I'm not really sure.

```
timed/static/14:32:27.725246.xml.chunks
```

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the mongo shell, instead of doing

```
db.strange_table/name.find()
```

You can also do

```
db['strange_table/name'].find()
```

To drop a table, you can just remove all entries from it:

```
db['strange_table/name'].remove()
```

And, if you're so inclined, after removing all of it's contents, you can also run

```
db['strange_table/name'].drop()
```